# why to use classes inside namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

I wish to know the actual reason behind writing the class names inside namespace. What purpose do they solve? Do they include the classes or do something else? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
namespace ns3 { 
class Channel;
class SpectrumChannel;
class MyMod;                        ;

class NewModule : public NetDevice
{   
public:
// methods and data
}
```

Comment: search `forward declaration`

Comment: Thanks, so  is this a way to tell the compiler that I am going to use these classes in the future, so keep them prepared? I am puzzled because the include files for the above doesn't include the files in which the classes (Channel, SpectrumChannel, MyMod) are defined.

Comment: It tells the compiler "I will give you more detail on what these contain later, but I need you to know that they exist now". In the typical case, this means that somewhere there is a class that takes a reference or pointer to one of those classes, but this isn't the right place to actullay define the content - or there is a mutual relationship between the clases, so class X is needed by class Y, and class Y refers to X in some way.

Comment: Thanks Mats, your explanation is very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good practice to put your classes into a namespace in order to avoid a name collision with other code (libraries) you might use (also coming in later in a project). When using common names like `Vector`, `Logger`, etc. as class names it can easily happen that they are also used in other code you want to use. When you put your classes into a (well considered) namespace, this chance of a name-collision is minimized.

Forward declarations are a different (independent) topic. When classes are defined within a namespace, also their forward declarations must be done within that namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I still have the following question : 
 
Is this a way to tell the compiler that I am going to use these classes in the future, so keep them prepared? I am puzzled because the above file doesn't include the files in which the classes (Channel, SpectrumChannel, MyMod) are defined.

Comment: For parsing a C/C++ compiler needs to know what identifiers refer to types. If inside a file only a pointer or a reference to a type is used, the compiler does not need to know the details of the type (size, methods, ..) for compiling that single file, so a forward declaration suffices. You need forward declarations if you have cyclic dependencies of types in your code. Another reason for using forward declarations is faster compiling (the class definition of a forward declared type does not need to be parsed and when the class changes you do not have to recompile code only using forward decl)